# PHP - Creating a class named 'Default'

Tags: php, class, default

I know that **default** is a reserved keyword in PHP. I came up to this weird situation where I wanted to name my class **Default**, but it seems whenever I try to create it in any place in code my whole page turns blank and PHP is not showing any error. It's just really confusing and I spent over 20 minutes searching for the problem in my code. Because i'm annoyed by that, I want to know what's wrong with this.

(I've tried even with different namespaces, but still the same effect, for example:)

```
new \SomeNamespace\Default();
```

Can someone explain for me why this is happening and there isn't any error showing up? Is this just a PHP flaw that we have to live with?

Comment: _my whole page turns blank and PHP is not showing any error_ - Enable `display_errors`

Comment: This is a syntax error, so there's no  output. Check the PHP error log.

Comment: Just out of curiocity, why do you want to name your class 'Default'? Apart from it being a keyword, what does it do? Shouldn't it be named 'DefaultSettings', 'DefaultController', 'DefaultCustomer' or whatever?

Comment: For some reason display_errors don't work for me in this case. I will see what I can find in error log.

Comment: try using `print_r(error_get_last());` to see if it shows any error.

Comment: Naming a class `Default` is really a BAD idea for numerous reasons.

Comment: This is a `PHP Parse error`, and there's really no way around it - `default` is a reserved word. As noted by some of the guys above it's an unusual name for a class. You have no choice but to think of another name I'm afraid!

Comment: @GolezTrol  Because I have a namespace like: `\Page\Controllers`, that class is inside it, and I don't like repeating things. That's why I wanted to call it 'Default' and not 'DefaultController'. Then I would refer to it with full namespace, and not by using `use`.

Comment: Then call it `Index`. I think naming the default controller is not your biggest  challenge in app.

Comment: @kba I know it's not. But naming is often tricky for me, that's why I like simplicty.

Comment: its cool, naming things is one of the trickiest things in computer science.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php

> These words have special meaning in PHP. Some of them represent things which look like functions, some look like constants, and so on - but they're not, really: they are language constructs. You cannot use any of the following words as constants, class names, function or method names. Using them as variable names is generally OK, but could lead to confusion.

Simply no no no. It is not possible whatever your script outputs errors or not. Try to name your class with better meaningful noun.

Comment: Yeah, that's right... I will rename it to something else. I found an error in logs, so I will remember to check it more frequently. Thanks for help guys ;)

Comment: actually you can name a class method `public function default(){}`

Comment: Hi. Yes, you can do it now but from PHP 7.0+.